# WCF MaxReceivedMessageSize will not update when changed in the web.config

Tags: silverlight, wcf, wcf-binding, basichttpbinding

I've looked around on the web and none of the solutions to this problem seem to work for me.  I have a WCF service being consumed by a Silverlight application.  Everything works fine until I attempt to update a large object graph.  My trace logs greet me with the lovely error:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been
>   exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize
>   property on the appropriate binding element.

I've changed the setting in both my web.config file and in the Silverlight's ClientConfig file and even tried manually creating the proxy and setting the value in code.

My web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
      <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true"
             messageFlowTracing="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBindingSettings" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="TestConfigService">
        <endpoint address="" contract="PreferencesUI.Hub.PreferenceSVC.ITestConfig" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingSettings" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

My Silverlight:

```
        EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:37935/TestConfig.svc");


        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
        binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 5, 00);
        binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 5, 00);
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 5, 00);
        binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 5, 00);
        binding.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;


        _preferenceTSTServiceProxy = new TSTC.TestConfigClient(binding, ea);
```

Does anyone see what I've missed here?  Everything I find on the web points out that someone forgot to either set maxReceivedMessageSize or forgot to give the endpoint a bindingConfiguration name value (both of which I've done).

Answer (score 0):

Uggh. I hate this particular aspect of WCF. It's unnecessarily complex to understand, and hard to get right.

I don't claim to understand it all, but I know that there are other places where the "MaxReceivedMessageSize" property can be set, in addition to the binding proper. Also try the underlying transport, like so:

```
    <binding name="CustomBinding_IRoomService">
      <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
    </binding>
```

Or like this:

```
private void AddNetTcpEndpoint()
{
    var binaryMessageEncodingTcp = new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement
    {
        MaxSessionSize = ushort.MaxValue
    };
    binaryMessageEncodingTcp.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = ushort.MaxValue;
    var tcpDuplexBinding = new CustomBinding(
        binaryMessageEncodingTcp,
        new TcpTransportBindingElement {MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue, MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue}
        );
    tcpDuplexBinding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
    tcpDuplexBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    tcpDuplexBinding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    tcpDuplexBinding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

    AddServiceEndpoint(
        typeof (IRoomService),
        tcpDuplexBinding,
        "tcpDuplex").Behaviors.Add(new SilverlightFaultBehavior());
        }
}
```

And there may be other places as well.

Comment: the basicHttpBinding doesn't have an httpProtocol element.  Changed it to a customBinding to get access to that config element and still no dice.  thanks for the suggestion though.